# Reading all matches from attribute value XML C#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, xmlreader

I have a code which retrieves only one value from the xml file using xmlreader.

```
<recordset>
    <itemidlist>
        <itemid idtype = "plant">787484545</itemid>
        <itemid idtype = "seed">659988222</itemid>
    </itemidlist>
    <itemidlist>
        <itemid idtype = "plant">90327328</itemid>
        <itemid idtype = "seed">099849999</itemid>
    </itemidlist>
    <itemidlist>
        <itemid idtype = "plant">34545488</itemid>
        <itemid idtype = "seed">787555444</itemid>
    </itemidlist>
</recordset>
```

And C# coded this entry:(s is the xml file)

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(s))
{
    var nodecount = 0;
    var plant = "";
    var seed = "";
    var typeid = false;
    var typeid2 = false;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
            reader.Name == "recordset")
        {
            nodecount++;
        }

        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
            reader.Name == "itemid")
        {
            var idtype = reader.GetAttribute("idtype");
            typeid = idtype == "plant";
            typeid2 = idtype == "seed";
        }
        while (typeid && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
               reader.Name == "itemid")
        {
            plant = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }
        while (typeid2 && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
               reader.Name == "itemid")
        {
            seed = reader.ReadInnerXml();
        }
    }
}
```

and this happens when a add to datagridview:

Only one record was found:
Plant     Seed
787484545 659988222

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only setting on `seed` and one `plant` variable, so if any more than one value is found it will be overwritten.  How do you propose to return multiple values?

Any reason not to use LINQ to XML for this?

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(s);

var plants = doc.Descendants("itemid")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("idtype") == "plant")
    .Select(x => x.Value);

var seeds = doc.Descendants("itemid")
    .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("idtype") == "seed")
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vl0rJV) for a working demo.

Comment: The reason why im not using this method is that the xml file is stored in a zip file. I use a code which confirms xml reading:                                                 String file_path = source_path.ToString(); //C:/users/me/xml_content.zip       using(var zip = ZipFile.Read(file_path)){                                                          using (Stream s = zip["Itemfile\\xml_content.zip"].OpenReader()){

Comment: I don't follow. It being in a zip file isn't particularly relevant. `XDocument.Load` has an overload that takes a stream, just like `XmlReader.Create`.